# Scope Event Receiver to WebApplication (SharePoint 2010)

Tags: event-receivers

I'm working on creating an event receiver which facilitates synchronization between two lists.  I originally created the receiver as a sandbox solution and after successful testing deployed it to production.  The problem I ran into was that because the receiver got called so frequently by the end of the day we hit our '300 Server Resource' limit for usercode objects.  Because I can't lower the amount of times the receiver gets called, I'd like to rescope it to the WebApplication for two reasons:

1) Avoid UserCode resource limitations
2) Policy dictates I can't deploy to GAC.

I attempted to rescope my receiver to WebApp by:

1) On the original project, set the SandboxSolution to false and set Assembly Deployment Target to WebApplication
2) Started a new project scoped as a farm solution and set to WebApplication.

Both receive the error: "Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object." when I attempt to debug.

Can anybody guide me in what might be causing this error?

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Event Receivers can go into GAC or Sandbox, but that the only options. You can't deploy them to the bin folder as they are called by TimerJob, PowerShell, CommandLine, ....